# ng-show and ng-hide doesn't work in chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a little chrome extension with angularjs and bootstrap. I have a alert like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errorMailZR">error</div>
```

and in angularjs controller :

```
$scope.errorMailZR = false;
```

i put it to false because i see the alert by default, it's not hidden :/ but in single web page when i go on it with browser, everything is ok. So, what i need for it's works in chrome extension ?

ng-show="false" doesn't work too in chrome extension...

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp#!

In order to run angular on an extension page, you have to use the ng-csp directive, or satisfy the ng-csp policies. I'm assuming you've done this, or nothing would be working at all.

Doing so turns off inline style insertion, this line in particular in angular.js (showing for reference, not for modification!):

```
!window.angular.$$csp().noInlineStyle && window.angular.element(document.head).prepend('<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>');
```

To get directives that rely on classes like ng-hide, ng-animate, ng-cloak,  to work, manually link to the classes using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/angular/angular-csp.css">
```

That's all there is to it.

### OLD HACKY STUFF

Immediate fix, add this to your document head:

```
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
```

Ng-show and hide work by angular adding the class ng-hide to items that are hidden and removing it when they are shown.

Why doesn't it work in extensions?
Good question. For whatever reason (will update when I find the reason) chrome extensions prevent that style tag from being added to the head. It's probably some kind of security thingy, and there's probably a way to turn off that security bit, I'll update when I find out more.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug chrome extension in chrome, just click right on extension popup. my guess is that angularjs isn't loaded or bootstraped in your extension, from my experience you should rather load angular from local files rather than CDN

Comment: but all others methods of angularjs works... the scope with text works, submit events, etc... angularjs is loaded locally. i have no errors :/